# How to prove that the number of unique prime factors is the number of idempotent elements contained in $\mathbb Z_n$

Tags: prime-factorization

Since the number of unique prime factors is connected to the number of idempotent elements contained $ \mathbb Z_n$, Denoted as;
    $ | I_n |= 2^j$ , where j is number of unique prime factors contained in $\mathbb Z_n$
Example: $ \mathbb Z_ 6 = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ the idempotent elements are $I_6 = \{0,1,3,4\}$ By unique prime factorization $n=(p_1)^k(p_2)^k...(p_j)^k$,then 6= (2)(3). Therefore the generalization on getting the number of idempotent elements in $\mathbb Z_n$ is ;  $ | I_n |= 2^j$ how do I formally prove this

Comment: $x^2=x$ gives $x(x-1)=0$. Since $x,x-1$ are relatively prime, each factor $p_i^{a_i}$ from $n=\prod_ip_i^{a_i}$ is either on $x$ or not. That is the $2^i$. Once you have chosen which prime powers from $n$ go into your $x$, or what is the same a factor $a$ from $ab=n$ with $(a,b)=1$ there is a unique $q$ with $(q,b)=1$ such that $aq(aq-1)=0\pmod{ab}$. This is $q=a^{-1}$.

Comment: Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem?  That might help